# using method in namespace that have same name with I'm working now on

Tags: c#, namespaces

It is strange....

there is a namespace named **Android.Graphics** and I'm work in the namespace named **Xamarin.FormsBook.Platform.Android**.

There is one more namespace named **Xamarin.Forms** and it has Color field.

Now, I want to use **Android.Graphics.Color** so I write Color then something recognize it as **Xamarin.Forms.Color** not **Android.Graphics.Color**.

[image]

And, If I write **Android.Graphics.Color** the builder could not find Android.Graphics. If I write Android. then builder find **Xamarin.FormsBook.Platform.Android** 's methods and fields.

[image]

If I write **Android.Graphics.Color** outside of namespace region, then it recognize.

[image]

But I can't assign any value in it since 'A namespace can not directly contain members such as fields or methods'.

help me, I want to use Color of Android.Graphic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using an [alias directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
using AndroidGraphics = Android.Graphics;
```

You can then refer to the `Android.Graphics.Color` type by using the alias name `AndroidGraphics.Color`.  Since there isn't another namespace called `AndroidGraphics` your compiler will resolve it correctly.

Alias directives can also be used for individual types, so you could also do the following:

```
using AndroidColor = Android.Graphics.Color;
```

and then refer to the type using `AndroidColor`.